# Selenium/Testng: Skip or Fail rest of @Test if an Exception occur

Tags: selenium, testng

I am writing my test case using `Selenium` and `TestNG`.

How can I skip/fail the rest of a Test when an exception is caught?

I tried to catch block in every @Test. Each @Test is based on priority which dependents on previous ones.

For example like if I have 3 steps on a test

```
@BeforeTest
public void login(){
}
@Test(priority = 1)
public void Verifytabs() {
}
@Test(priority = 2)
public void checkhomepage() {
 }
@Test(priority = 3)
public void clickonProfile() {
}
@AfterTest
public void logout()
{
}
```

Comment: You don't have to skip them, TestNG will automatically skip any test case which depends on a failed test case.(See Subburaj's answer on how to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of your `Test` method depends on other test method, then you can use the `dependsOnMethods` annotation.

**Sample Code:**

```
@BeforeTest
public void login(){
}
@Test(priority = 1)
public void Verifytabs() {
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"Verifytabs"})
public void checkhomepage() {
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods={"checkhomepage"})
public void clickonProfile() {
}

@AfterTest
public void logout()
{
}
```

Here, If `Verifytabs` Test method fails,then all the dependent method will be skipped and If it is passed, then all the dependent method will be executed.

Comment: I have catch block in each method with SYSO ,so all are getting Passed as a final output and it goes in next @Test. Due to which dependsOnMethods is not working.

Comment: @Shruti: Whether you are testing the Exception in your Test? If not, then you need to add some assertion inside the catch block (`Assert.fail("Exception is occurred");`) to fail the test

Comment: Thanks,when I added Assert.fail("Exception is occurred"),Its printing above message with whole stack of error,Is there any option to avoid it?

Comment: @Shruti: Have you added any other statement within the catch block?

Comment: @Shruti: Hope this answer solved your requested problem.Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark button and also give the upvote.